# Perl, to pass valuse down csv file where missing.

Tags: perl, csv

I am trying to fill in the gaps in a csv file with information from above in the csv file.

I have a CSV file with three columns in order called Mb_size, tax_id, and parent_id. There is a relationship between tax_id and parent_id, for example, in the csv file at the end where you have 22.2220658537 for the mb size, 5820 is the tax id and 5819 is the parent id. As move up the file 5819 the parent id will be seen in the tax id column. The parent id can be repeated but tax id is uniqie in its column.

At the top of the csv file some of the taxa id have corresponding MB size next to them. I want to pass these values down to fill in the gaps. So if there is a taxa id with no mb size next to it, take it from the above by using the parent id and taxa id relationship.I am trying to alter a previous script I have but I cant get the relationship coded.

The example input file:

```
Mb_size,tax_id,parent_id

377.810518214,1,1
377.810518214,131567,1
377.810518214,2759,131567
288.886032927,5819,2759
6565.2,999923,2759
466.7350035,147429,2759
22.2220658537,5820,5819
184.801317,4557,147429
,4575,147429
555.55,1234,5819
,4321,999923
,9999,4321
```

The example output:

```
Mb_size,tax_id,parent_id
377.810518214,1,1
377.810518214,131567,1
377.810518214,2759,131567
288.886032927,5819,2759
6565.2,999923,2759
466.7350035,147429,2759
22.2220658537,5820,5819
184.801317,4557,147429
466.7350035,4575,147429
555.55,1234,5819
6565.2,4321,999923
6565.2,9999,4321
```

The code I have :
     use strict;
     use warnings;

```
 open taxa_fh, '<', "$ARGV[0]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[1]" for input: $!\n};
 open match_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_passedDOWN.csv" or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

 my %node_data;
 my %parent;
 my @node_order;
 my $header;
 while ( my $line = <taxa_fh> ) {
 chomp( $line );

   if (1 == $.) {
      $header = $line;
      next; 
     }

     my @fields    = split( /,/, $line );
     my $Mb_size   = $fields[0] || 0; 
     my $tax_id    = $fields[1];
     my $parent_id = $fields[2];

  $parent{$tax_id} = $parent_id;
  push @node_order, $tax_id;
  $node_data{$tax_id} = $Mb_size;
}

 print match_fh "$header\n";
 for my $id ( @node_order ) {

  if ( exists $node_data{$tax_id} ) {
         print match_fh "$Mb_size, $id, " . $parent{$id} . "\n";

      } else {
         $parent = $parent{$parent}
     }

     }

    close taxa_fh;
    close match_fh;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -F, -lape '
    next if $. == 1;
    $F[0] = $size[$F[2]] if $F[0] eq "";
    $size[$F[1]] = $F[0];
    $_ = join ",", @F;
' input.file > output.file
```

I'm assuming that there will not be a case where a line with an empty size also has a parent with an empty size.